# Get Bounding Box of Each Polygon (Each Rows in a table) using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, bbox

I have zoom level 4 polygons of the world (in EPSG 3857) and I am trying to get the bounding box of each tiles.
[image]

this is the query that I used but this is not working.

`select title, id, st_extent(geom) from world_tile4;`

[image]

ST_Extent brings me the entire table (feature) and this is not what I wanted to have 
[image]

I am assuming that I might have to use for loop to get this?

Comment: What you want is ST_Envelope or box2D - not ST_Extent.

Comment: @RalphTee Oh.. my mistake. Thank you so much for your tip.

Answer (score 2):

`select *, st_asText(ST_Envelope(wkb_geometry)) as bound from world_tile4;`

ST_Extent -> St_Envelope
this was the key.

[image]

Comment: This should work as well `select *, ST_AsText(ST_SetSRID(ST_Extent(wkb_geometry),3857)) as bound  from world_tile4 group by ogc_fid;`

Comment: @user30184 why do you have to group by the feature id?

Comment: Because as you saw in the initial error message, ST_Extent is an aggregate function. Using "group by" with any unique field makes each row to be an own aggregate.